# How to store strings in apps that are 100% equals except the database and the strings?

Tags: php, gettext

I'm working in some php web apps that are almost identic, except content database, texts, and themes. Let's think in some similar like could be stackexchange sites.

The objective is mantain only one project in the same repository, so if I introduce a new feature, I only have to implement once, and not for every site.

For the themes and database is not a problem, but for the texts I don't know how can I proceed (now the texts are hardcoded in the php files).

I've googled and searched in SO, and I've find some questions similars like this where the answer was using gettext for i18n. 
But in my case, it's not exactly i18n, because some of the sites are in the same language but the texts are different.

How can I store these strings?

Comment: What do you mean by texts?  Do you mean the page content, like a CMS?

Comment: @BadHorsie No, the page content is stored in a DataBase. By Texts I mean something like the title of the page or button's text.

Comment: If more details are needed, or something is not enought clear, please let me know

Comment: And if downvoting, please explain the reason, so at least then I will know how to improve the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of ways to get this done. I have a fitting project-scenario where I archive different things in different ways:

- All instances of a project come from the same SVN folder.
- Each instance has its own config-file, which is not included in SVN.

In addition to that, every project has its own:

- Textbase (Labels, etc)
- Templateset
- Content

I use my own translation-system to distribute the textbase over my instances. You can use some of php's build in functions: http://verens.com/2008/04/03/translation-in-php/

The Templateset is just done by a config-variable that sets the root directory for the template-engine: `./templates/instance-x/...`

The content could also referenced by a config-variable. In my case, I have a shop-system, that uses a product-base, which is used by all instances identically. To make a product available/visible to the public, you have to assign it to a category. Categories and instance-dependent.

Categories got a instance-specific ID (in my case its the `shop_id`).

Answer (score 1):

You could for example create a table called "texts" in each database that contains the specific texts for that app. As you already have to connect with a different database for each app, you can easily implement to always get `SELECT value FROM {current_database}.texts WHERE key = "headertext"` or so.

That way, your code can stay the same and only the databases differ from each other.

**UPDATE:** And of course i18n localization is also easily implemented this way, by adding another column to the `texts` table containing the localization value (like `en`, `de` or `nl` etc.)